# How to do history.js in Rails the right way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, history.js

## Hi everyone,

it's now my fourth try to implement history.js in a Rails app. I have one approach that is running quite okay, but the code is so ugly. Today again I looked at the code and thought: How can I make this better, easier, more DRY?!

## What I have done so far (and working quite okay, not perfect):

- Set `remote: true` to my links
- jquery-ujs fetches the `js.erb`

My HTML looks like:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    some content with buttons, etc.
  </div>
</body>
```

The `js.erb` contains:

```
History.pushState(
  {
    func: '$(\'#content\').html(data);',
    data: '<%= j(render template: "news/index", formats: [:html]) %>'
  },
  'test title',
  '<%= request.url %>'
);
```

And then history.js takes the function and gives it the data. So it replaces the `content`-div with the new generated code. And it also updates the URL. This code I have to put in every(!) `js.erb` file.

## My last thoughts to make it a bit less ugly were:

- Set `remote: true` to my links
- When a link gets clicked it fetches some `js.erb` which replaces the `content`-div
- All links with `data-remote="true"` will get a `ajax:success`-handler
- On `ajax:success` the new URL gets pushed to history.js

But there's still one problem within. Then I have JavaScript code:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', 'a[data-remote="true"]', function() { ... });
```

The problem is: `ajax:success` never fires if I replace the `div`-tag where the link (that should fire the event) was in.

***Maybe someone can solve my problems...***

## Or is there a better way?

Comment: I've looked at the histoy.js page a bunch of times but have never mustered the effort to actually try it. I'd love to see this question answered in a clear way.

Comment: PJAX is HTML5 only. HTML4 browsers just get normal links... With history.js we'd get AJAX for HTML4 browsers too

Comment: But maybe the PJAX code is really the answer, the only difference should be, that PJAX uses history.pushState and I'd have to use History.pushState ;) I'll habe a look at this tomorrow

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? And what tutorial did you first follow to come up with this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I followed no real tutorial. I just grabbed all the information about history.js and combined them ;) To your first question: No, still no solution :(

Comment: I'll second that: PJAX is the way to go. For the few POSTs and PUTs you might do (I've not seen PJAX work well with <form>s), you can supplement it with history.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only use jquery-ujs and pushState, popState.

See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27532946/345996

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
    var state = History.getState();
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the *beforeSend* event as global listener for all data-remote to change the handle the history of the browser.
I prefer the beforeSend because I want the link to change as soon as it is clicked, regardless of the result of the ajax request...

```
$(document).bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(event,data){
    history.pushState(null, '', event.target.href)
});
```

This solve your problem because the event is fired before any modification to the DOM is done.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/) ?
It will be default in Rails 4.